# Problem with installing libtiff5-dev

Tags: 14.04, dependencies

I am new to the whole Linux OS, and I have been having trouble installing some packages, including `libtiff5-dev`, `libtiff5` , `libjbig-dev` and `libmagickcore-dev`. I keep getting the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libtiff5-dev : Depends: libtiff5 (= 4.0.3-7) but 4.0.3-7ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
                Depends: libjbig-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

However I do not know what to do. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Have you tried to refresh your packages list before with `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: Tried using `sudo apt-get update` and afterwards `sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev` with no successful results

Answer (score 0):

> libtiff5-dev : Depends: libtiff5 (= 4.0.3-7) but 4.0.3-7ubuntu0.1 is
>   to be installed.

Clearly the user had disabled trusty-updates and trusty-security repos at some early point after install.

So  libtiff5 4.0.3-7ubuntu0.1 (from trusty-updates or security repo), is installed but now the only available version of libtiff5-dev is the release version of 4.0.3-7.  The version of both packages must match exactly, that's why libtiff5-dev can not be installed.

Re-enabling those repos would have solved this issue..

Answer (score -1):

Add the `Is not going to be installed packages to the main installation list

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev libtiff5 libjbig-dev
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying